# Xamarin Forms iOS status bar text color

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am unable to change the status bar text color of my Xamarin Forms iOS app to white. I have change in my info.plist as follow:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Yet the color still remain black.. Is there another way to change the status bar text color?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Xamarin.Forms, there are three things you need to do to achieve white text in the iOS Status Bar. I've also posted a sample Xamarin.Forms app below that uses white text in the iOS Status Bar.

## 1. Update the Info.plist

In `Info.plist`, add the Boolean Property `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set its value to `No`

[image]

## 2. Use a NavigationPage & Set the Navigation Bar Text Color to White

In the `Application` class (typically `App.cs`), the `MainPage` must be a `NavigationPage`, and the `BarTextColor` must be set to `Color.White`
[image]

## 3. Clean & Rebuild the App

Sometimes the compiler doesn't update the Status Bar Color until you Clean and Rebuild the app, so after making the changes in steps 1 & 2, clean the app and rebuild it.
[image]

## Sample App

https://github.com/brminnick/SaveImageToDatabaseSampleApp/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But now i don't have a status bar anymore :/

Comment: Oh no! Do you mind asking that as a new question on StackOverflow and sending me the link? I can post some screenshots to help you debug that problem too

Comment: Hey, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321309/xamarin-ios-status-bar-text-color 

Thank you

Comment: The actual values to go into Info.plist (for example for windows users):
 <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <false/>

Comment: I had to change the info.plist directly. The change in the editor did not seem to affect the file. This could be a bug in Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to change status bar in IOS for me was to use this code in FinishedLaunching in AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();

    LoadApplication (.....);
    app.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);

    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```

Comment: This method is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622923-setstatusbarstyle

Comment: @Singapore you have to change "View controller-based status bar appearance" to false in info.plist (as shown in the accepted answer).

Comment: I had to change the info.plist directly. The change in the editor did not seem to affect the file. This could be a bug in Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 4):

So what I did for changing *status bar color* and *status bar text color* is:

**Info.plist**

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<!--<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>-->
<!--<true/>-->
```

**AppDelegate**

Inside function *FinishedLaunching()*, add code below:

```
UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
if (statusBar != null && statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
{
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#7f6550").ToUIColor(); // change to your desired color 
}
```

**App.xaml**

I added code below to change status bar *text color* to *White*.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type NavigationPage}">
     <!--<Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Black" />-->
     <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Be careful: UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView; cause exception since iOS 13 (iPhone 11, for example), check OS version before use it. UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Select the `NavigationBar` and change the `Style` property to `Black`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding this to `AppDelegate` `FinishedLaunching` worked:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
```