# Xamarin.iOS Status Bar Disappears When Changing Its Text Color

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How do I avoid hiding the Status Bar on Xamarin.iOS when changing its text color?

After trying to change the color of my iOS Status Bar, I don't have a status bar anymore.

I remove the property I added in `info.plist`, but then my status bar text color remains black.

This is what I did, [following these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273050/5953643):

- Updated `info.plist` adding the boolean property `View Controller-Based Status Bar Appearance` and set it to `No`
- Added in the App.cs, in my MainPage which is a NavigationPage, `BarTextColor = Color.White`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to hide the iOS Status Bar. Here are the things to verify in the Xamarin.iOS source code:

## 1. Info.plist Setting

In the `Info.plist`, ensure that `Status bar is initially hidden` is `No`

[image]

## 2. `StatusBarHidden` Property

Search the code to find any references to `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden` and ensure that it is `false`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change Status bar color:

in App.xaml.cs:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("Your color code here"),
    BarTextColor = Color.White
};
```

in `Info.plist`:

`<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>`

check this url :   http://www.fabiocozzolino.eu/change-ios-status-bar-color-xamarin-forms/